# How do I leave an organization on Google Play Store Developer Console that I've been added to?

Tags: google-play

I've been added in a couple of organizations on Google Play Store Developer Console but I can't get in touch with the admins, how can I leave those organizations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is now possible.

Go to **Users and permissions** then click on **Manage** on the right side of the row showing your email address. Then on the next page click on **Remove user**.

Comment: This only works if you have permission to view/modify users on the account.

Answer (score 18):

Currently there is no way of doing it, but this request has been communicated to the Google Play console team.

Comment: I have got the same issue, added by different organization and now they have deleted there GSuite. It really creates a lot of clutter.

Answer (score 1):

It's been 4+ years and still, there isn't a way to leave the organization other than to contact someone with admin rights. It's still under construction  in 2023 I guess: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35889152